# AngularJS submitting form to another state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a main page with just a single search box.

```
<div class="input-group" ng-controller="MainSearchCtrl">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="term">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="search();">Search</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

My main search controller looks like this.

```
app.controller('MainSearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$state', function($scope, $log, $state) {
$scope.search = function() {
    $log.debug("searching for", $scope.term);
    $state.go('index.search', {q: $scope.term});
}
}]);
```

I am using u-router for my states.

```
$stateProvider.state('index', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "app/views/common/content.html"
}).state('index.main', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "app/views/main.html"
}).state('index.search', {
    url: "/search?:q",
    templateUrl: "app/views/search.html"
});
```

My content.html has a `<ui-view/>` in it and the main page renders fine but when I want to submit the search, my browser location simply does not change.

Instead of `http://localhost:7000/#/search?q=param` I always get `http://localhost:7000/#/?q=param`. This causes my `main.html` template to also load which is not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try with `url: "/search/:q"`?

Comment: @Michelem yes tried that. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to specify a route in `ui router` using query parameters is like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('index', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "app/views/common/content.html"
}).state('index.main', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "app/views/main.html"
}).state('index.search', {
    url: "/search?q",
    templateUrl: "app/views/search.html"
});
```

Notice the missing ':' before `q` in the second route. Hope this helps.